# Laravel8 role based access using and pivot tables and middlewares

Tags: access-control, laravel-8, user-roles, laravel-middleware

I am trying to write a large project using laravel8 and will need role based access. So I have created a roles table and linked it to the users table via a modal table called role_user. Now I am able to create the access and perform checks inside controllers and users model and everything works correctly
my problem is that this way I have to keep checcking if a user has access in each and every function for all my user access levels and this is tedious.

I have thus tried to convert this approcah and use middlewares but the problem is that I am unable to redirect the users to the appropriate dashboard upon authentication and they are both being redirected to the home page that is designated for users only.

I have tried the following

1. I have addes the following code to the users model to create a many to many relationship  between the users and the roles and also to check if the user has roles and peform appropriate tasks as per the code blocks

   ```
     public function roles() {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }
    public function checkRoles($roles)     {
    if ( ! is_array($roles)) {
        $roles = [$roles]; 
        return false;   
     }
    if ( ! $this->hasAnyRole($roles)) {
        auth()->logout();
        abort(404);
    }
   }
   public function hasAnyRole($roles): bool    {
    return (bool) $this->roles()->whereIn('name', $roles)->first();
   }

   public function hasRole($role): bool    {
    return (bool) $this->roles()->where('name', $role)->first();
   ```

   }
   Now this would have worked if I proceeded to peforem checks on each controller's model directly but after creating middlewares for each role and peforming checks in each as follows things failled
2. a) Admin Middleware

   ```
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next){
      if (Auth::user() &&  $request->user()->hasRole('admin')) {
        return $next($request);
      }
     return redirect('home')->with('error','You have not admin access');
    }
   ```
3. b) SuperAdmin Middleware

   ```
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next) {
    if (Auth::user() &&  $request->user()->hasRole('super_admin')) {
        return $next($request);
   }

   return redirect('home')->with('error','You have not permission to peform this task');
   }
   ```
4. Now after registering all the middlewareds inside the Kernel class, I modified the login Controller class and added the following code inside the construct function:

   ```
    if(Auth::check()){
        if(Auth::user()->hasRole('super_admin')){
            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::SUPERADMINADMINHOME);
        }elseif(Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')){
            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::ADMINHOME);
        }elseif(Auth::user()->hasRole('vendor')){
            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::VENDORHOME);
        }else {
            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        }
    }
   ```
5. I also updated my routes as follows

   ```
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'super', 'as' => 'super.', 'namespace' => 'Super', 'middleware' => ['Super']], function () {
        Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\SuperAdminController::class,'index'])->name('superadminhome');
    });
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'middleware' => ['Admin']], function () {
       Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::class,'index'])->name('adminhome');
    });
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'vendor', 'as' => 'vendor.', 'namespace' => 'Vendor', 'middleware' => ['Vendor']], function () {
       Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\VendorController::class,'index'])->name('vendorhome');
    });
   ```

After doing all this, I tried tom login with the superadmin credentials and the admin credentials but all of them take me to the same page home. What could I be doing wrong or where can I get step by step guide to how to achieve this task noting that I am new to middlewares in laravel.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see you are having this problem becasue the checks are all yielding false hence the last is being taken into account. That would mean that the way in which you are checking for the roles is probably wrong. I would suggest looping through the roles and using a switch statement. checking if it matches the ones you need and then redirecting appropriately.
This would mean changing your if statements that check for the availability of a specific roles.
That is this part of your code

```
    if(Auth::user()->hasRole('super_admin')){
     return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::SUPERADMINADMINHOME);
 }elseif(Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')){
     return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::ADMINHOME);
 }elseif(Auth::user()->hasRole('vendor')){
     return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::VENDORHOME);
 }else {
     return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
 }
```

Comment: Would you mind giving me a clue on how to do the looping? I guess I need a for each loop but on what do I run it?